# How can I count the number of XML nodes that contain a specific value with SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I have an XML structure like:

```
<foo>
  <bar>
    <baz>blue</baz>
  </bar>
  <bar>
    <baz>yellow</baz>
  </bar>
  <bar>
    <baz>blue</baz>
  </bar>
</foo>
```

There could be any number of  nodes, containing any text string. I want to use SQL to return a key value ONLY for the rows where there are more than 5  nodes that contain the text "blue." The only thing I've been able to find online is how to count the number of  nodes:

```
SELECT @xml.value('count(/foo/bar/baz)', 'int')
```

Comment: What do you mean `return a key value ONLY for the rows where...` what is a key value in this context (node name? node value?) and what are rows (you only have a variable)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question's XML only has two nodes containing `blue`, but to return those nodes with at least 5 `blue`s as requested...

```sql
with QualifyingNodes as (
  select
    x.n.value('local-name(.)', 'sysname') [local-name],
    x.n.value('(text())[1]', 'nvarchar(50)') [text]
  from @YourXml.nodes('//*[text()="blue"]') x(n)
)
select *
from QualifyingNodes
where [local-name] in (
  select [local-name]
  from QualifyingNodes
  group by [local-name]
  having count(1) > 5
);
```